# Issue with AJAX call of images paths, converting JSON message into javaScript array and trying to display the images?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, cordova

Trying to load images from a PHP array into a javaScript array using JSON messages and AJAX. Using the function buildImage() to load the first image in the array into the div content. Using onclick to change the image to the next one in the array. Im very new to AJAX and JSON. The conversion between the JSON message and javaScript array is the major issue for me.

PHP

```
<?php
include("mysqlconnect.php");

$select_query = "SELECT `ImagesPath` FROM `offerstbl` ORDER by `ImagesId` DESC";
$sql = mysql_query($select_query) or die(mysql_error());   


$data = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql,MYSQL_BOTH)){
$data[] = $row['ImagesPath'];
 }

 echo $images = json_encode($data);

 ?>
```

This is the client side script

```
<script>
var images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

function importJson(str) {
    // console.log(typeof xmlhttp.responseText);

    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=images;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://content.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function buildImage(src) {
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = src
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    buildImage(images[i]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload= "importJson();" onload= "buildImage();" >

    <div class="contents" id="content" onclick="buildImage()"></div>

 </body>
```

Comment: Why did you change the question to do what it says in @atlavis's answer? Is it still not working with that fix?

Comment: What is the value of `$data` in PHP?

Comment: Usually JSON is used for sending arrays and objects. If you're sending HTML, you don't need to use JSON. Just `echo $data` in PHP and use `innerHTML = responseText` in JSON.

Comment: No it's not fixed, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Please put back the original question. Otherwise, the answer makes no sense, since it's saying to do what you already do. If you want to show your updated code, add an UPDATE at the end.

Comment: $data is list of paths to image files.

Comment: You mean an array? Then you need to parse it and then use a `for` loop to add each of them to the HTML.

Comment: do you see content of `xmlhttp.responseText;`? how it looks like?

Comment: You can't have two `onload` attributes in the `body`. If you need to run two functions, you should put them in one attribute, separated with `;`.

Comment: Code is returned.. Doesn't JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText) parse it and doesn't the for loop in the buildImage function add them.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous. So `buildImage` is running before `importJson` loads the images.

Comment: The `for` loop isn't in `buildImage`.

Comment: + `for` loop runs before `xmlhttp.responseText` is ready. Anyway, I still want to see how `responseText` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You call `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)` before `xmlhttp.responseText` is ready.

Call it when response is ready

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
   images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=images;
}
```

Comment: Question is edited to show what I have now. Would "xmlhttp.responseText" instead of images be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. You have to parse the JSON and run the `for` loop in the `onreadystatechange` function

```
<script>
function importJson(str) {
    // console.log(typeof xmlhttp.responseText);

    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            images = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                buildImage(images[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","http:/content.php");
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function buildImage(src) {
    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = src
    alert("1");
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload= "importJson();" >

    <div class="contents" id="content" onclick="buildImage()"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Currently, image is broken. Thank you for all your help

Comment: What does `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` show?

Comment: Uncommented in it's current position. Nothing appears

Comment: No, you have to do it in the callback function. Don't you understand how AJAX works?

Comment: @MichaelF: because you call it too early. Put it wthin `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {...}`

Comment: Nothing is ever printed to the console. It's in the correct position now. I'm being trying to alert the "xmlhttp.responseText" too but it won't will function.

Comment: Your URL is wrong. There should only be one `/` before `content.php`. With two slashes, `content.php` is the server name.

Comment: You should be checking the Javascript console for errors, it would have told you that it got an error trying to make the call.

Comment: Please learn basic debugging tecnhiques, you can't depend on everyone else to do this for you all the time: http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Comment: URL is correct, in the code above I just used an example URL apologies for that miscommunication.

Comment: Still, check the console for errors. Also, go into the Network tab, click on the AJAX URL, and look in the Response section to see what it's sending back.

Comment: This is what the PHP file echo and they are the paths to the images i want to display. ["http:\/\/servername\/~mmg6\/swipeApp\/images\/07-08-2014-1407418088.png","http:\/\/servername\/~mmg6\/swipeApp\/images\/07-08-2014-1407418089.png"]

Comment: That looks correct. I can't explain why `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)` in the callback function doesn't show it. Are you sure the script isn't echoing anything before or after that?

Comment: Is it possible for me to access the web site?

Comment: I added the full php file above nothing is echoed more than what should be.

Comment: Is it possible for me to run your application?

Comment: The console is now active. The error I receive is XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sever/content.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Are you going through a webserver? You can't use AJAX with `file://` URLs.

Comment: The AJAX call has to come from the same domain as the server. So you can't send an AJAX request from a `file://` URL to an `http://` URL.

Comment: The php file is stored on a server. The html file which includes the AJAX is going to be stored on a Cordova application.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I added the html file to the same folder as the php and tried to load it in the browser the image still doesn't appear. Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do using cordova and ajax?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cordova.